# Is there any way to simplify $(A\land B \land C) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B \land \neg C)$?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have the following Boolean Algebra expression, shown below, and I'm at a loss as if it can actually be reduced further. I was thinking some kind of XOR but 3 input XOR gates aren't really what can be used here :S

$$X =(A\land B \land C) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B \land \neg C)$$

Can anyone help out here real quick?

Comment: Not sure if this really helps but the right part can be $\neg(A \lor B \lor C)$.

Comment: The expression is true iff A,B,C are all true or all false. You can come up with many logical expressions with the same end result but I doubt that you will find a (much) shorter form.

Comment: Its CNF is $$\left(a \vee \neg b\right) \wedge \left(a \vee \neg c\right) \wedge \left(b \vee \neg c\right) \wedge \left(c \vee \neg a\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You want to say $A,B,C$ are all the same (truth value). It is enough to say that $A = B$ and $B = C$. And you can quite easily say "$A = B$" using XOR and NOT, so the resulting expression would have just 2 XORs and 2 NOTs and 1 AND. That's the simplest solution I can think of using only AND, OR, NOT, XOR.